# Updating values in a dictionary list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.6, updates

Suppose you have a dictionary that has a list of dates (pulled from excel as floats) as a value within a sub-dictionary of counties.

```
 master_dictionary = {'MO': {
   'Lincoln County': [43378.0, 43378.0, 43378.0],
   'Franklin County': [43357.0, 43357.0],
   'Camden County': [43208.0, 43208.0, 43208.0],
   'Miller County': [43208.0],
   'Morgan County': [43208.0, 43208.0]},
  'WI': {'Marathon County': [43371.0, 43371.0, 43371.0, 43371.0, 43371.0]},
  'NJ': {'Atlantic County': [43340.0, 43340.0]}}
```

My goal is to 1) get the max value of these 'date' and, 2) convert the max 'date' to a `'%M/%D/%Y'` value using `datetime.strftime`. I am able to get the max value and convert it, but I am trying to get it to update the date values in the master dictionary. How can I do this?

```
for key, value in master_dictionary.items():
    counties = value
    for k, v in counties.items():
        d = max(v)
        year, month, day, hour, minute, second = xldate_as_tuple(d, book_datemode)
        n_date = rawDate = (str(month) + "/" + str(day) + "/" + str(year))
        print(n_date)
```

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: Something like this: `master_dictionary = {'MO': { 'Lincoln County': ['4/22/2018'], 'Franklin County': ['12/3/2017'], 'Camden County': ['7/11/2018'], 'Miller County': ['6/20/2018'],'Morgan County': ['6/6/2018']},'WI': {'Marathon County': ['12/21/2017']}, 'NJ': {'Atlantic County': ['10/5/2017']}}` Basically, each county will have the most current date. Bonus if I could get the date to no longer be a list item, but just a regular value in the 'counties' subdictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use something to get the `i = np.argmax(v)` (numpy) so you have the index, then access that location and update with `master_dictionary[key][k][i] = n_date`. In case you want to replace the whole list, use `master_dictionary[key][k] = [n_date]`, and you dont need the argmax thing. Good luck!

Comment: I guess OP doesn't want it to be a list. So you probably mean `master_dictionary[key][k] = n_date`.

Comment: I modified this solution slightly and it worked great. Generally, my questions are a much simplified version of the actual problem but using both `master_dictionary[key][k] = n_date` and `master_dictionary[key][k] = [n_date]` seemed to work in my situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the **xldate_as_datetime** function from the [xlrd](/questions/tagged/xlrd) library:

```
for key, val in master_dictionary.items():
    for skey, sval in val.items():
        # temporary assignment to overwrite dates
        # with max for the given county (skey)
        cdate = xldate_as_datetime(max(sval),0).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        # assign the max date to 
        # the county in master_dictionry
        master_dictionary[key][skey] = cdate
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually the easiest way to go about these is to make a new dictionary, instead of trying to modify an existing one (This is espescially true if you're adding or removing keys):

```
from xlrd import xldate_as_datetime
from pprint import pprint

new_dict = {k: {k1: xldate_as_datetime(max(v1),0).strftime('%m/%d/%Y') for k1, v1 in v.items()} 
            for k, v in master_dictionary.items()}

pprint(new_dict)
```

prints

```
{'MO': {'Camden County': '04/18/2018',
        'Franklin County': '09/14/2018',
        'Lincoln County': '10/05/2018',
        'Miller County': '04/18/2018',
        'Morgan County': '04/18/2018'},
 'NJ': {'Atlantic County': '08/28/2018'},
 'WI': {'Marathon County': '09/28/2018'}}
```